# Is there any problem with having the origin on the liveserver differ from what originally shows when I click on the website

Tags: javascript, html

Good day I want to connect with this server and
This is how my html file is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket IO</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<h1 id="Get Response From The Server">---</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.4.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('wss://ws2.qxbroker.com/socket.io/',{transports:['websocket']});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it on live server it shows this as origin in devtools

[How the origin looks on liveserver](https://postimg.cc/BjktKhNF)

And this is how the origin looks normally if I visit the site
[The qxbroker.com site](https://postimg.cc/7J8WJyJR)

It brings back a session id with ping and pong interval(ms) either way but my question is if the difference in origin would have any negative effect on the connection when I want to send messages to this server